# Magento 2: Redirect with Data in Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect

I have this code to redirect to custom page from observer.
But I wonder how to redirect from observer, and with data transfer to the redirected page.

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // do something

        // redirect
        $this->redirectToMyCustomPage($observer);

        return $this;
    }

    public function redirectToMyCustomPage($observer) {
        // get error url
        $url = '/namespace/module/action';

        // setting an action flag to stop processing further hierarchy
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);

        /// redirecting to error page
        $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah found it.

 We only need to transfer params through the url, like this:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // do something

        // redirect
        $this->redirectToMyCustomPage($observer);

        return $this;
    }

    public function redirectToMyCustomPage($observer) {
        // get error url
        $url = '/namespace/module/action?myparams=abc';

        // setting an action flag to stop processing further hierarchy
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);

        /// redirecting to error page
        $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        return $this;
    }
}
```